# Develop the same java class in two different packages one for UAT and one for production

Tags: java, package, resolution, production, uat

I come across a situation where I need to put a code block that is needed only for unit tests or QA, and it must not be present for production. This must be implemented so that the code is maintainable and readable. I am thinking about this and below is one approach, but I need help to finalize it...

Develop the class `ServiceClient` which needs to invoke a REST Service with SSL. The service needs to initiate `SSLContext` and on the UAT environment, we need to add this code block to be executed only in the test environment:

```
package com.uat.environment;
public class ServiceClient extends com.prod.environment.ServiceClient {
...
...
    static {
        //for localhost testing only
        javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(newJavaKeyword javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier() {
            public boolean verify(String hostname, javax.net.ssl.SSLSession sslSession) {
                if (hostname.equals("localhost")) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
...
...
}
```

Note: replace the keyword above `newJavaKeyword` with `new` as it won't let me post it using new for some reason.

The above code block will disable matching the hostname for localhost with the self-signed certificate owner/issuer `CN=Tom Akehurst` for WireMock.

The correct version of the class `ServiceClient` intended for the production environment will be developed in the package `com.prod.environment` as follows without the static code block above:

```
package com.prod.environment;
public class ServiceClient {
...
...
  public void ServiceClient() {
    ...
    ...
  }
...
...
}
```

Then, will ensure to configure maven `pom.xml` to generate two jar files `service_uat.jar` and `service_prod.jar`. That is, one will have the UAT package, and the other will have the production package. When running the program using `java.exe' I want to configure the` classpath`so that if the UAT jar file is present in the classpath, then when the client code references the class name`ServiceClass`it will pick the UAT version. And, if I don't add the UAT jar and only add the prod jar to the classpath, then the client code will pick the`ServiceClass` from the prod package.

The client code will be something like the following:

```
import com.prod.environment.ServiceClass;
import com.uat.environment.ServiceClass;

public static void main() {
  ...
  ServiceClass service = new ServiceClass();
  ...
}
```

What I want to happen is that if the UAT jar is present, it should pick the UAT version, if not, it will pick the prod version.

I am not sure how to achieve this objective... I think the compiler will report an error if I try to import the same class name from two different packages.

What is the appropriate way to achieve this?

---

## Update:

I am thinking about this ... maybe we can introduce a factory class called `ServiceClientFactory`. This class will be responsible for referencing/creating the correct version of the `ServiceClient` class and triggering the static block. The `ServiceClientFactory` will check if the package `com.uat.environment` is present and then reference the class using `com.uat.environment.ServiceClient`, if not present then reference the prod version `com.prod.environment.ServiceClient`.

I am nor sure how to do that and appreciate your help.

Comment: Cannot you put both UAT and PROD jar files in your class path with UAT jar ahead of the Prod jar?

Comment: That's why I'm asking this question! Can you share your answer with some details?

Comment: java -cp "......:uat.jar:prod.jar:...." MyMainClass

Comment: But how to resolve the class reference? Are you saying I should specify the same package qualified name for both classes? I can't create the package twice unless it's in a separate project and doesn't look a good idea! I'm not sure if I'm following you correctly!

Comment: Java searches for a class in the jar files in the same order as they are specified in the class path. Once it finds one, it will stop. So, it doesn't matter if a class is defined more than once. Yes, they need to have the same package names. You may also need to have two projects. I have seen this kind of techniques widely used in very large java projects.

Comment: If your project is small, and you don't feel like to split it, you can also specify your service "provider" classes in a configure file. You will run the UAT class if it exists. Otherwise, run the production one.

Comment: @CjY sorry, I don't follow you. Please provide more details. I don't know how to configure service provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254751/discussion-between-tarekahf-and-cj-y).

Comment: I think you could use a [Service Provider Interface](https://www.baeldung.com/java-spi) and create two providers for the service, one for the production environment and another for other environments.